# Zend retrieve router variables

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

Zend talk.I know this **basic difference** beetwen **getQuery** and **getParam**:

- **getQuery** retrieves values from the query string.
- **getParam** retrieve also variables set by the router.

**Question:** What if I only want to retrieve variables set by the router(not paying attention to the query string)?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a method `getUserParams()`. This retrieves only self set params. Maybe this can help you out.

Comment: You are right, there is no talking about this method in the manual. But you will find it in the api-documentation: http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/ . If you are using an IDE with code-completition you will also see it. It's defined in `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract::getUserParams()`